# Select and Update Oracle BLOB column with XMLQUERY

Tags: xml, oracle, blob

I have to update XML values stored in an BLOB column in Oracle 11G. The BLOB has stored a comlete XML file in which i have to update some values and save it back as a BLOB. How can i easily SELECT and UPDATE the data wit blob conversion and XMLQUERY AND XMLUPDATE? Any code examples?

Thank you in advance.

Here are some more details:

Here is the ddl of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE MAPSHEET
(
  MAPSHEETID NUMBER (14,0) NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2 (64) NOT NULL,
  STRUCTURE BLOB,
)
```

the xml data in the blob col STRUCTURE

```
<MapSheet Version="1.0">
    <Frame>
        <JobId>9022165</JobId>
        <LayoutId>24807064</LayoutId>
        <Blocks>
            <Block MapFieldMask="true" CompressText="false" CombineRaster="false">
                <Name>layout</Name>
                <StyleId>24808857</StyleId>
                <LayoutLayers>0 1</LayoutLayers>
                <BlockScale/>
                <JobItemIds/>
            </Block>
            <Block MapFieldMask="true" CompressText="false" CombineRaster="false">
                <Name>karto</Name>
                <StyleId>24809031</StyleId>
                <LayoutLayers>4</LayoutLayers>
                <BlockScale/>
                <JobItemIds>
                    <JobItemId>9083675</JobItemId>
                    <JobItemId>9088148</JobItemId>
                </JobItemIds>
            </Block>
            <Block MapFieldMask="true" CompressText="false" CombineRaster="false">
                <Name>hel</Name>
                <StyleId>24809032</StyleId>
                <LayoutLayers>-</LayoutLayers>
                <BlockScale/>
                <JobItemIds>
                    <JobItemId>9022173</JobItemId>
                    <JobItemId>25403646</JobItemId>
                </JobItemIds>
            </Block><Block MapFieldMask="true" CompressText="false" CombineRaster="false">
                <Name>shade glacier</Name>
                <StyleId>24809041</StyleId>
                <LayoutLayers>-</LayoutLayers>
                <BlockScale/>
                <JobItemIds>
                    <JobItemId>24806040</JobItemId>
                </JobItemIds>
            </Block>
            <Block MapFieldMask="true" CompressText="false" CombineRaster="false">
                <Name>shade</Name>
                <StyleId>24809040</StyleId>
                <LayoutLayers>-</LayoutLayers>
                <BlockScale/>
                <JobItemIds>
                    <JobItemId>24806038</JobItemId>
                </JobItemIds>
            </Block>
        </Blocks>
        <Offset X="0" Y="0"/>
        <Name>DS</Name>
    </Frame></MapSheet>
```

This simple SELECT to get the data does not work:

```
SELECT x.MapSheet
FROM XmlTable('/MapSheet') PASSING XmlType(MAPSHEET.STRUCTURE,1)
    COLUMS "XML" VARCHAR2(300) PATH 'MapSheet') AS x;
```

How can i select/update the desired xml data out of the blob colum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For selecting from XML you can either use `ExtractValue(XmlType, XPath)` or `XmlTable` to transform the Xml clob into a queriable table of XML. For BLOB converstion, you should be able to just wrap it with `XmlType(blob_value, 1)`, then you can perform any of the XML related function on it.

```sql
SELECT ExtractValue(
          XmlType('<test><node1>value1</node1><node2>value2</node2></test>'), 
                  '/test/node1') as Node1 
FROM dual;
```

Or using `XmlTable`

```sql
SELECT xt.Node1, xt.Node2
FROM XmlTable('/test/block'
         PASSING XmlType('<test>
<block><node1>value1a</node1><node2>value2a</node2></block>
<block><node1>value1b</node1><node2>value2b</node2></block>
<block><node1>value1c</node1><node2>value2c</node2></block>
</test>')
        COLUMNS
        "Node1"     VARCHAR2(20)   PATH 'node1',
        "Node2"     VARCHAR2(20)   PATH 'node2') AS xt;
```

Using UpdateXml, assuming the record I am updating has the above XML in a column:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable SET xml_data =
UpdateXml(xml_data, '/test/block/node2[text() = "value2b"]/text()', 'value2z')
WHERE data_id = 1;
```

The above should update the `node2` that had the value `value2b` to now have `value2z` instead. Which then returns the new XML and assigns it to the column `xml_data` in the record that matches `data_id = 1`.

One note, in the above query, it is working with a column that is already of the type XmlType. You are working with a `BLOB`. I would ask, is there a reason for it being `BLOB` instead of `CLOB` or `XmlType`? If you are storing `VARCHAR` type data you should really be using one of the latter two types, `CLOB` if you are storing various `VARCHAR` data, and `XmlType` (which is a more specific type of `CLOB` anyway) if you are storing strictly XML data.

If you are stuck using the `BLOB` data type you will need to perform a lot of conversions. Using `XmlType(blob_data, 1)` should get you from `BLOB` to `XmlType`, but going back you will likely need to use `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(xml_data)`. So the query would become:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable SET clob_data =
UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(
    UpdateXml(XmlType(clob_data, 1), '/test/block/node2[text() = "value2b"]/text()', 'value2z').GetClobVal()
)
WHERE data_id = 1;
```

Here is a working stand alone example showing the various methods mentioned above:

```sql
DECLARE varchar_data    VARCHAR2(500);
        blob_data       BLOB;
        xml_data        XMLType;
        node1Val        VARCHAR(20);
        node2Val        VARCHAR(20);

BEGIN
    select '<test>
<group><node1>value1a</node1><node2>value2a</node2></group>
<group><node1>value1b</node1><node2>value2b</node2></group>
<group><node1>value1c</node1><node2>value2c</node2></group>
<group><node1>value1d</node1><node2>value2d</node2></group>
</test>' into varchar_data from dual;

    select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(varchar_data) into blob_data from dual;

    select XmlType(blob_data, 1) into xml_data from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(xml_data.getClobVal());

    select xt.Node1, xt.Node2
    into node1Val, node2Val
    from XmlTable('/test/group' 
        passing XmlType(blob_data, 1)
        columns Node1     VARCHAR2(20)    path 'node1',
                Node2     VARCHAR2(20)    path 'node2'
        ) xt
    where xt.Node1 = 'value1c';
    dbms_output.put_line('node1Val = ''' || node1Val || ''', node2Val = ''' || node2Val || ''';'); 

    -- Using UpdateXml to update the XML, that will return an XmlType 
    -- so we call GetClobVal() to let CAST_TO_RAW convert to BLOB.
    select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(
        UpdateXml(
            XmlType(blob_data, 1), 
            '/test/group/node2[../node1/text() = "value1c"]/text()', 
            'zzzz').GetClobVal()
        ) into blob_data
    from dual; 

    select XmlType(blob_data, 1) into xml_data from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(xml_data.getClobVal());

    select xt.Node1, xt.Node2
    into node1Val, node2Val
    from XmlTable('/test/group' 
        passing XmlType(blob_data, 1)
        columns Node1     VARCHAR2(20)    path 'node1',
                Node2     VARCHAR2(20)    path 'node2'
        ) xt
    where xt.Node1 = 'value1c';
    dbms_output.put_line('node1Val = ''' || node1Val || ''', node2Val = ''' || node2Val || ''';'); 

END;
```

Comment: Hi, i can't use the ExtractValue command any longer because it's deprecated. So i have to try it with XmlTable in your example. But there is the blob to clob conversion missing and the same for the update statement, the simple wrap around XMLType(blob_value) method is not working. Can you please add the complete syntax for it. Would be great!

Comment: @happymapper - Sorry forgot to include the parameter to indicate characterset (1 = USASCII) in the `XmlType` function.

Comment: Your select example is still not working, because the XMLType syntax is still using XML data. The blob is used in our table because this is a default setting of our system and i should not change this.

Comment: What do you mean the XmlType is still using XML data? I will update my answer with a working stand alone example.

Comment: I've meant that your passing XmlType(....)  statement works with pure XML data instead of the needed blob data type. Your stand alone example is perfect. I really appreciate your support and your advice, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table testxmlBlob (p blob);
```

Insert some xml document into table.

```
insert into  testxmlBlob values( utl_raw.cast_to_raw('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer''s Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book></catalog>')) ;
```

View inserted xml.  `xmltype(blob,csid -charset enocoding id '0' is default)`

```
select xmlserialize(document xmltype(p,0)) from  testxmlBlob;
```

Use xmlquery to change   `<description>`  to  `<descriptionNew>`. 
it also can be used in update statement `update testxmlBlob set p =  XMLQuery(....) ...`

```
 select XMLQuery('copy $i := $p1
              modify
              (
             for $j in $i/catalog/book/description
             let $newn := <descriptionNew>newDescription</descriptionNew>
             return replace node $j with $newn)
             return $i             
             ' PASSING xmltype(p,0) AS "p1"     
          RETURNING CONTENT) readable
          ,xmlserialize(document XMLQuery('copy $i := $p1
              modify
              (
             for $j in $i/catalog/book/description
             let $newn := <descriptionNew>newDescription</descriptionNew>
             return replace node $j with $newn)
             return $i             
             ' PASSING xmltype(p,0) AS "p1" 
          RETURNING CONTENT) as BLOB) blob_value
          from  testxmlBlob;
```

[Other example how to use xmlquery to update](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/app_depr_upd.htm#ADXDB6159)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Everthing fine now!